# In IE11, why does this flex item not change according to its container's height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

This question is almost the same as one of my previous questions, but it's specifically focused on IE11, as the answer of the previous question worked on all other browsers. IE11 is a special case because of its many flexbox bugs, hence the new question.

**What I'd Like to Happen**

I have a `.box` whose height is constrained to stay within the viewport. Nested a couple levels within this element I have a `.content-body` that contains a header and a `.content` item. I'd like for just `.content` to shrink (with scrollbars displayed) when the height of `.box` is small enough.

[image: How it looks in modern browsers (as intended)]

**What Happens**

In IE11 only, it gets cut off because the content doesn't want to shrink.

[image]

**The Code**

I made a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/pndalal/pen/PWyMoG) to demonstrate the problem. Simply resize the height of the browser and observe how the content element responds. Below is the same code on StackOverflow for posterity. The ideal solution will leave this working the same on all other browsers, but fix it for IE11.

```css
/* the most relevant rules to the problem */

.container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: calc( 100vh - 50px );
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box-body { 
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  min-height: 0;
}

.content-body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content{
  overflow: auto;
}

/* other stuff (appearance mostly) that probably doesn't matter */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box{
    /* appearance */
  width: 600px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
}
.box-body{
    /* appearance */
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.content-header{
  /* appearance */  
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.box-label {
  /* appearance */
  padding: 30px 10px;
  background: teal;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.content{
  padding: 10px;
}

p {
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="box">

    <div class="box-label">
      Header
    </div>

    <div class="box-body">

      <div class="content-body">
        <div class="content-header">
          Content Header
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <p>Mr do raising article general norland my hastily. Its companions say uncommonly pianoforte favourable.</p>

          <p>On projection apartments unsatiable so if he entreaties appearance. Rose you wife how set lady half wish. Hard sing an in true felt. Welcomed stronger if steepest ecstatic an suitable finished of oh. Entered at excited at forming between so
            produce.</p>

          <p>Answer misery adieus add wooded how nay men before though. Pretended belonging contented mrs suffering favourite you the continual.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="box-label">
      Footer
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

IE requires `height` attribute defined for scrolling. If you change your `max-height` to `height` for your `.box` element, it will work in IE as well.

Comment: Using `height` changes the box to expand to full height though. Also, even though the box does scroll with this solution, it stops shrinking when some minimum is reached, then it clips.